# Appending outer html with input number in it

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get tbody html to append to another table. And this table have an input number in it.

```
  <tbody class="onetable tbody">
      .....
      .....
           <input type="number" value=""/>
      .....
  <tbody>
```

Before appending this tbody, I change the value of the input of number, forexample 3.

However, after placing the tbody to another table, the value of input reset to 1, not 3.

```
    var wholeTbody = $("#onetable.tbody").prop('outerHTML');

    $("#anotherTable").append(wholeTbody);
```

How to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read the value from first table inputbox and set it to anothertable inputbox.

Comment: I am just appending the tbody directly, and it should placing the whole value in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the values in the `outerHTML` unless you set it manually as `value` attribute.

```
var wholeTbody = $("#onetable.tbody").find("input[type='text']").attr("value",function(){
  return this.value;
}).end().prop('outerHTML');

$("#anotherTable").append(wholeTbody);
```

Comment: @iyal What are all the other elements there rather than textbox ?

Comment: the most important thing is the input of number `input[type='number']`, the rest  is hardcode.

Comment: @iyal Sorry I couldn't understand. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: For now I just need to change your code from `input[type='text']` into `input[type='number']`, because this time what I only need is only that type. But someday maybe I will need all type of textbox.

Comment: But this has achieve what I need for a moment.

Comment: @iyal Oh great. Glad to help! :)